# Reply to .msg file with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, msg, reply

I have a .msg file saved locally and I'm trying to reply to it using Excel VBA. I have this code, which just takes the .msg file as a template, but does not reply to it.

I googled a lot, but I am not sure how to do this.

Any help would be appriciated!

```
Sub ReplyMSG()
Dim objOL As Object
Dim Msg As Object

Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
inPath = "C:\temp"

thisFile = Dir(inPath & "\*.msg")
Do While thisFile <> ""

    Set Msg = objOL.CreateItemFromTemplate(inPath & "\" & thisFile)
    Msg.Display
    thisFile = Dir

Loop

Set objOL = Nothing
Set Msg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: your code does open the file properly and you will find yourself ending in the edit mode of the mail. what is your concrete desired output? Automatic reply? could you be more specific?

Comment: Every month or so, I get a bunch of emails with some data as an attachment. I always save the email locally as a msg. file and then process the data in my Excel workbook. I would like to have a VBA in my workbook, connected to a button that replies to that email as you would in Outlook clicking the reply/reply all button and generates pre-written subject and body of the email with some of the cell values from that workbook. That e-mail is always the same, just the parts that I will be pulling from the cell values change.

Comment: I'm able to do that with `Msg.HTMLBody = "<html><head></head><body>" & mailbody & "</body></html>"` and defining the `mailbody` in the VBA as HTML text further in the code. It generates the email, but I think that `CreateItemFromTemplate` does not show the previous conversation, just my generated e-mail. I am not sure what to use in order to show the previous conversation in the e-mail, just like it would be when replying in Outlook. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub replyMsg()

Dim objOL As Object
Dim objNamespace As Object

Dim msg As Object
Dim replyMsg As Object

Dim inPath As String
Dim thisFile As String

Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")

inPath = "C:\temp"

thisFile = Dir(inPath & "\*.msg")
Debug.Print thisFile

Do While thisFile <> ""
    
    Set msg = objNamespace.OpenSharedItem(inPath & "\" & thisFile)
    
    Set replyMsg = msg.Reply
    
    msg.Close 1     ' olDiscard https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.OlInspectorClose
    Set msg = Nothing

    replyMsg.display
    thisFile = Dir
    
Loop

Set objOL = Nothing
Set objNamespace = Nothing

End Sub
```